# Make multiple logic expresion shorter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there a way to make this example expression shorter:

```
if x == line[0] or x == line[1] or x == line[2] or x == line[3]:
```

I don't want to use:

```
if x in (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]):
```

But rather thinking if there is a possibility to make this expression looking like:

```
if x == (line[0] or line[1] or line[2] or line[3]):
```

or

```
if x == y (y: line[0] or line[1] or line[2] or line[3])
```

It could be obvious for most of programmers, however I could not find the answer.

Comment: `if x in line:` or perhaps `if x in line[:4]:`.

Comment: @ekhumoro what if line has 5 more elements in it?

Comment: In that case, `if x in line[:4]`

Comment: What problem do you have with `if x in (line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]):`?

Comment: I thought It will require only partial string (x) to make match/True, but it actually works fine. If you know what I mean: x = "txt" y = "ABCtxtDEF" x in y ---> True, for more arguments z = "whatever" x in (y,z) --> False. So it does what I want. Cheers guys. Idiot me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if x in line[:4]:
```

It will look for `x` in the first four elements of `line`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could just do:
`if x in line[:4]:`
But you have to be careful with that because in calls `__contains__`, and line doesn't have to implement in, unless it is a string or something like that.

Comment: `x in line[:4]` will use `line.__contains__` if defined, but if it isn't, Python will fall back to effectively iterating over `line[:4]` and comparing `x` to each element one by one.